# How to determine the block device of a user's home directory in C?

Tags: c, linux

I am looking for a Linux function to get the block device on which a user's home folder is mounted on.

Let's say the /home directory is mounted on /dev/sda1, and the username1 home directory is on /home/username1. I need a function call that returns back /dev/sda1 for /home/username1.

```
(/dev/sda1)/home
              |
              |/username1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-do-i-find-on-which-physical-device-a-folder-is-located

Comment: No, I am looking for a C function. I think I found it though and the function is https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, I found the answer here:
https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat

st_dev: Is the id of the disk containing the file and is made of the major+minor number of the device.